# Laravelを利用してAmazon S3に画像を保存できない

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

Amazon S3で画像を保存したいと思いましたが、下記エラーで保存ができません。
アクセス権限は許可しています。

**putでファイルを送信するとエラーが出力される:**

[image: putでファイルを送信するとエラーが出力される。]

.envのアクセスキー及び、シークレットアクセスキーも誤りがないのでそのへんは関係ないのかなとは思うのですが。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ちなみに以下のようにバケットから画像を取得することはできます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

S3のバケットから画像の情報のgetはできるのですが、putはできない状況です。何か考えられる原因がありましたらご教授いただければと思います。

---

viewファイル

```php
   <form action="{{route('upload')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
              <input type="file" name="file">
             <button type="submit">保存</button>
 　</form>
```

コントローラ

```php
  public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'file' => 'required|image'
        ], [
            'file.required' => '画像が選択されていません',
            'file.image' => '画像ファイルではありません',
        ]);
        $file = $request->file('file');
        //dd($file);
        $list = Storage::disk('s3')->files('');
        //dd($list);
        $path = Storage::disk('s3')->put('/', $file, 'public');
        //dd($path);
        return redirect("/");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

エラーが出たら「どんなエラー内容なのか」を確認してみることをお勧めします。私自身は Amazon S3 を使用したことが無いので具体的な回答はできませんが、まず「amazon s3 put access denied」で検索すると以下のトラブルシューティングが見つかります。

[Amazon S3 から 403: Access Denied エラーをトラブルシューティングする方法](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/)

また、一般的な話をするなら取得 (参照) は自身で設定されたパブリックアクセスでの権限で問題ないのでしょうが、新しくファイルを書き込むには別の権限が必要になってくるのだと思われます。まずはこの辺りをチェックしてみてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。一度書き込み権限を確認してみます。